# SVG loaded by URL doesnt resize with CSS

Tags: reactjs

I have a avatar, which is loaded by url from the backend-server, but when trying to change width or using transform to downscale, nothing changes.

```
<img 
  className='navbar-avatar' 
  src={'http://localhost:8000' + userProfile.avatar}
/>
```

[image]

I want it to be smaller and be next to the username. Before the image i had a react icon which could be scaled with the "size" property.

Answer (score 1):

Take into consideration, now your svg is not an svg element. It's an image. Because of that you can set the size of the icon using the width and height of the image.

Look at this online example: https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-danny-49hmnh?file=/src/App.js

Basically, we have on the react part:

```js
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <img className="navbar-avatar" src="/icon.svg" alt="profile avatar" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

And the css:

```
.navbar-avatar {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}
```

You can play with it and change size and svg to test :)

Comment: Mhh so it doesnt really change anything, size is the same and i dont understand why xD

Comment: Did u check the sandbox? Did it work for u?

Comment: Yes it works in the sandbox but not on my project :(

Comment: Also the weird thing is that the resizing does work in another part of the project

Comment: Ok so now its really getting confusing...it does work with inline styling wtf